# Как получить значения из результатов парсинга сайта с помощью AngleSharp?

Tags: c#, html, anglesharp

Решаю задачу парсинга страницы Google с ответами на запрос. Использую AngleSharp. С горем пополам добился того, чего хотел.
Получаю результат отбора по селектору span и в этом меня все устраивает. Однако мене нужно считать href ссылку предка, я ее вижу в отладчике, но вот как ее считать программно я совершенно не понимаю. Использую для программирования C#.
Прикрепляю изображения с местом откуда не могу считать данные.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как туда достучаться?
Это элемент, куда я получил данные.
мой код

```
    //создание документа используя библиотеку AngleSharp

IConfiguration config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();

var document3 = BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(myUrl).Result;

if (document3.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Ничего не получилось =  { document3.StatusCode}");
}

HashSet<string> hrefTags = new HashSet<string>();
HashSet<string> tdTags = new HashSet<string>();
var reffs = document3.QuerySelectorAll("a");
var tdTaggs = document3.QuerySelectorAll("span");
var spanClass = document3.QuerySelectorAll("span")
             .Where(element => element.TextContent == ">");

//определяем достижения конца списка
string nextURL;
if (spanClass.Count() != 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Двигаться дальше можно");
    //считываем ссылку для движения дальше
    nextURL = spanClass.Parent(); // вот сюда нужно считать href из предка, но достучаться до него не знаю как
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Двигаться дальше нельзя");
    //генерируем признак окончания чтения
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее информация про предка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И теперьто, что мне нужно считать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо

Comment: 1) нужно видеть html код, а не скрины непонятно чего 2) нужно видеть ваш код, который не работает. А вообще есть QuerySelector с использованием CSS селектора. href - это атрибут, сначала получаете ноду, потом берете у нее нужный атрибут типа `string link = node.GetAttribute("href");`

Comment: Вставил код и пометил проблемное место. Посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: вы серьезно? я же уже сказал, что делать, в вашем случае `nextURL = spanClass.Parent().GetAttribute("href")`

Comment: Спасибо. Вы натолкнули меня на правильные мысли и нахождение решения.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение.
решение выглядит следующим образом.

```
IConfiguration config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();

var document3 = BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(myUrl).Result;

if (document3.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Ничего не получилось =  { document3.StatusCode}");
}


HashSet<string> hrefTags = new HashSet<string>();
HashSet<string> tdTags = new HashSet<string>();
var reffs = document3.QuerySelectorAll("a");
var spanClass = document3.QuerySelectorAll("span")
             .Where(element => element.TextContent == ">");

//определяем достижения конца списка
string nextURL;
if (spanClass.Count() != 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Двигаться дальше можно");
    //считываем ссылку для движения дальше

    nextURL = $"https://www.google.ru{spanClass.ElementAt(0).ParentElement.GetAttribute("Href")}";
    
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Двигаться дальше нельзя");
    //генерируем признак окончания чтения
}
```

Comment: Используйте класс `Uri` для создания ссылок, старайтесь не использовать конкатенацию строк, это ненадежно. Для создания класса `Uri` по частям используйте класс `UriBuilder`.